# Code: 0x80073D05 error while downloading Ubuntu (windows subsystem for Linux) from windows marketplace

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed windows subsystem for Linux following steps (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) on my Windows 10 laptop.

OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
OS Version:                10.0.18363 N/A Build 18363

But when I try to get the Ubuntu via link:https://aka.ms/wslstore

[image]

I am getting error as shown below:

[image]

Note no resolution from links:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-winapps-appscat_games/error-code-0x80073d05-on-windows-10/a37b67c0-bde9-40e5-b785-ebfc635eccd2

https://ugetfix.com/ask/how-to-fix-windows-store-error-0x80073d05-on-windows-10/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to resolve this issue please download and install from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I think this is a better way to go than manually installing: that's gotta leave some artifacts behind and I don't know how that'd affect things.

This fixed it for me:

1. Go to "Add and Remove Programs"
2. Uninstall Ubuntu
3. Uninstall Windows Subsystem For Linux
4. Open a powershell terminal in admin mode
5. Run `wsl --update`
6. Run `wsl --install`

If this errors...

7. Run `wsl --unregister Ubuntu`
8. Run `wsl --update`
9. Run `wsl --install`

Also, see https://superuser.com/questions/1619233/completely-reinstall-wsl

Comment: I uninstalled it by following steps 1 to 3, then reinstall it via Microsoft Store. +1

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing this problem: `An error occurred during installation. Distribution Name: 'Ubuntu' Error Code: 0x80072efe` while running this command `wsl --install -d Ubuntu`.I check everything many times, like virtualization, subsystems for Linux, and everything enabled.

Then, I ran this command: `wsl --update` but i got another error: `Error: 0x80072efe`.

Then, I changed my wifi, connected my laptop to my phone's data via hotspot, and tried to run the `wsl --update` command. It runs successfully. `Windows Subsystem for Linux has been installed.`. Then I ran `wsl --install -d Ubuntu` which also run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

`wsl --install -d Ubuntu` from a Powershell window (as admin) worked for me!